# What should I do to improve the quality of the screen capture?

Tags: video-capture

I'm creating videos to post to YouTube.

My videos are about some jobs I do on the computer.

I watched some of my videos posted and that the quality of the video capture was not very good and clear.

**What should I do to improve the quality of the screen capture?**

To use better software?

I'm using [Windows Media Encoder](https://www.microsoft.com/pt-pt/download/details.aspx?id=98)

Answer (score 2):

Windows Media Encoder creates files in wmv format (I guess), which is highly compressed. Make sure you follow the [YouTube recommendations](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/1722171?hl=en)

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [OBS (Open Broadcast Software)](https://sourceforge.net/projects/obsproject/files/) for screen capture.

[Screen Capture with OBS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BHmcsVOuFVU)

It not best option, but it easy  to use and it free.

**Best solution:**
Capture to lossless codec like huffyuv, edit it and then encode for youtube (you can find tons guides about it).

It requires much more time to process, but you will get maximum quality.